# Reading a XML config file - Should I use xmlreader, xmltextreader or stringreader? (VB.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm looking to read a XML config file from my vb.net. It's programmed in using Visual Studio 2012 and dotnet Framework 4.  It's a simple config with the occasional nested XML node.

I've read a few things online and there seems to be some examples using XmlReader, XmlTextReader and StringReader.

Last time I did this was several years ago. Whats the recommended method these days?

If there's an example I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file and the contents?

Comment: To start with, just need to read the config file serially then use it to setup some global values for the application. THe file isnt very large with say about 10 config lines.   I would also later want to create a screen on another app to read/modify this config file